# Why wont my Jquery script target its specified files?

Tags: jquery, footer, gif

Hi I'm tearing my hair out with this code.
Im trying to get it to only target my GIFS because the plugin is working on everything I post.
I'm using HEADWAY and I have this in my footer.

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('body .post img').each(function(){

     // GET IMG SRC ATTR AS A STRING
     var GIFstr=jQuery(this).attr('src').toLowerCase();

     // IF STRING CONTAINS .GIF, ADD HYENA CLASS
     if( GIFstr.indexOf('.gif') )  jQuery(this).addClass('hyena');

  });

});

</script>
```

Im trying to get it to only target my GIFS because the plugin is working on everything  post.

Thanks.

Comment: `indexOf()` returns `-1` when not found. It's not a boolean.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Stephen, that went over my head unfortunately. How would I fix that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Hi Stephen, after reading that reference I've tried changing the object to lower case for the case sensitivity. " and also tried           if( gifstr.indexOf('.gif', 0))  jQuery(this).addClass('hyena');                          they both didnt work unfortunately

Comment: What Stephen is saying is that when you do GIFstr.indexOf(), it returns a number rather than a true or false value. You could do something like if (GIFstr.indexOf('.gif') > -1) {jQuery(this).addClass('hyena');
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `indexOf()` correctly.

```
// IF STRING CONTAINS .GIF, ADD HYENA CLASS
if( GIFstr.indexOf('.gif') !== -1 )  jQuery(this).addClass('hyena');
```